# How add a downarrow after an element with CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to add arrows to my sortable table on [this page](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/ffmap/list.html)

What I tried is adding this code to the css:

```
table th.headerSortUp:after {
   content: " &uarr;";
}

table th.headerSortDown:after {
   content: " &darr;";
}
```

But that will not display the arrows `"↑" and "↓"` but the html-entities instead: `"&uarr;" and "&darr;"`

or even better would be the up- and downward arrow I found here:
http://graphemica.com/search?q=ARROW+TO+BAR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using theirs unicode positions instead

```
table th.headerSortUp:after {
   content: " \2191";
}

table th.headerSortDown:after {
   content: " \2193";
}

table th:after {
   color: #123456;
}
```

See http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/entities/arrow.htm for other arrow symbols.

Comment: thanks, I used \2912 and \2913 for ⤒ and ⤓ now. How can I give the arrows another color than the rest of the content of the th?

Comment: I solved it with you help like this: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7003745 also see https://github.com/tcatm/ffmap-d3/pull/35